# strange namespace behavior when setting the ROS_NAMESPACE environment variable

Tags: ros, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a node publishing a topic let's say "my_topic". Simply running this node, rostopic list tells me as expected:

```
/my_topic
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Now, when I want to push this node to a namespace by:
export ROS_NAMESPACE=my_ns

rostopic list says:

```
/my_ns/my_ns/my_ns/my_topic
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Any idea where three times "my_ns" comes from? When I run the node from a launch file and set the "ns" attribute, everything is alright. I'm not doing anything fancy with namespaces etc. in the node, I put some example code below. It seems like this came with ros 1.4.8. It used to work with 1.4.6 which I had installed before.

Best, Markus

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "ns_test");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String> ("my_topic", 1);

  ros::Rate r(5);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    std_msgs::String msg;
    msg.data = "my string message";
    pub.publish(msg);
    r.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10676/strange-namespace-behavior-when-setting-the-ros_namespace-environment-variable/) by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-21**:
I have the same on diamondback/lucid.

**Comment by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) on 2011-07-21**:
I just tried with the electric beta, it happens there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a look into roscpp/src/libros/node_handle.cpp. It seems like this (lines 263 to 267) gets called multiple times and appends the namespace every time:

```
else if (!namespace_.empty())
{
  // ROSCPP_LOG_DEBUG("Appending namespace_ (%s)", namespace_.c_str());
  final = names::append(namespace_, final);
}
```

commenting out

```
final = names::append(namespace_, final);
```

avoided the problem, but no idea what this will break now ;-)

Best, Markus

---

Originally posted by [Markus Achtelik](https://answers.ros.org/users/867/markus-achtelik/) with karma: 390 on 2011-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2012-01-04**:
Well, it looks like when your ticket was addressed, it broke something else. :) Anyway just to connect the dots for anyone else having namespace headaches since moving to electric: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3617

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-07-21**:
Certainly seems like a bug to me especially if you can show the behaviour changed between 1.4.6 and 1.4.8. You should probably file a ticket against roscpp to be sure the developers are aware. Out of curiosity does it only affect topic names and not other things (node name, private parameters, etc)?